# How can I do something like this in PostgresQL?

Tags: postgresql

Here is the snippet that I would like to happen. Is this possible?

```
INSERT INTO join_table_1(table_1_id,table_2_id)
SELECT id, (INSERT INTO table_2(id) VALUES (uuid_generate_v4()) RETURNING id) 
FROM table_1
```

Looking at TRIGGER also but I can't find a way to return the id of the newly inserted row

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly clear to me what you are trying to achieve, but I think you are looking for a [data modifying CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING)

```
with new_t2 as (
  INSERT INTO table_2(id) 
  VALUES (uuid_generate_v4()) 
  RETURNING id
) 
INSERT INTO join_table_1 (table_1_id, table_2_id)
SELECT id, (select id from new_t2) 
FROM table_1
```

Comment: Haven't tried this yet but will this insert a new row to table_2 for every selected id from table_1?